# Model postion and rotation after using applyMatrix - ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I recently created a cylinder which sits on its side. I then add a cube to each of its segments by calculating the center point of each faces tris and have this working perfect with cubes.

I am now trying to replace the cubes with models. The model is a flat ground so essentially a cube. I am running into a few issues.

The first issue is that when I add the ground model to the cylinder, because the cylinder is on it's side the grounds 0,0,0 is flipped incorrectly. I fixed this by doing the following:

```
ground.model.scene.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(Math.PI / 2));
ground.model.scene.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.PI));
```

However, the next step in my logic which worked perfectly for the cubes was calculating rotation using look at and passing in the face normals and the position passing in the current face and calculating the center point of the two faces. Since each face of my cylinder is made up of two tris, I can trick it this way!

Those functions look like this:

```
averageFaceNormals(index){
   
      var faceAvg = new THREE.Vector3();

      faceAvg.x = (this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index].normal.x +
        this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index+1].normal.x) / 2;
     
      faceAvg.y = (this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index].normal.y +
        this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index+1].normal.y) / 2;

      faceAvg.z = (this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index].normal.z +
        this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index+1].normal.z) / 2;

      return faceAvg;
  }

calculateFacePositions(index){
  var geo = this.cylinder.geometry;

  var faceA = this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index];

  var verticesA = geo.vertices;
  var v1A = verticesA[faceA.a];
  var v2A = verticesA[faceA.b];
  var v3A = verticesA[faceA.c];

  var centroidA = new THREE.Vector3();
  centroidA.x = ( v1A.x + v2A.x + v3A.x ) / 3;
  centroidA.y = ( v1A.y + v2A.y + v3A.y ) / 3;
  centroidA.z = ( v1A.z + v2A.z + v3A.z ) / 3;
  
  var faceB = this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index+1];

  var verticesB = geo.vertices;
  var v1B = verticesB[faceB.a];
  var v2B = verticesB[faceB.b];
  var v3B = verticesB[faceB.c];

  var centroidB = new THREE.Vector3();
  centroidB.x = ( v1B.x + v2B.x + v3B.x ) / 3;
  centroidB.y = ( v1B.y + v2B.y + v3B.y ) / 3;
  centroidB.z = ( v1B.z + v2B.z + v3B.z ) / 3;

  var centroidAverage = new THREE.Vector3();
  centroidAverage.addVectors(centroidA, centroidB);
  centroidAverage.x = centroidAverage.x / 2;
  centroidAverage.y = centroidAverage.y / 2;
  centroidAverage.z = centroidAverage.z / 2;

  return centroidAverage;
}
```

Then this is where I am adding the ground tiles, I commented out the two lines responsible for rotation and position as they are no longer working with my model, but work perfectly with the cube test object I had been using. Am I overlooking something? The ground tiles spawn, but it is like the matrix change I made is overridden by the lookat and position copy.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < this.cylinder.geometry.faces.length; i+=2){
      var ground = new Ground("ground", this.preload);
      ground.model.scene.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(Math.PI / 2));
      ground.model.scene.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.PI));
      //ground.model.scene.lookAt(this.averageFaceNormals(i));
      //ground.model.scene.position.copy(this.calculateFacePositions(i));
      this.cylinder.add(ground.model.scene);
    }
```

EDIT: So I have currently made some progress and it seems to be working better with less code, but I have changed my placement loop to look like this:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < this.cylinder.geometry.faces.length; i+=2){
      var ground = new Ground("ground", this.preload);
      var afn = this.averageFaceNormals(i);
      ground.model.scene.up = afn.clone().normalize();
      ground.model.scene.lookAt(new Vector3(afn.x,afn.y,afn.z));
      ground.model.scene.position.copy(this.calculateFacePositions(i));

      this.cylinder.add(ground.model.scene);
    }
```

Which currently looks like this
[image]

It seems as though I just need to have each ground flip a rotational value to 0 but I am not sure how to go about doing this. Copy / Set don't seem to work, and I'm not sure if I need to be using eulers or vectors.

It is probably blaringly obvious, but this is my first time using ThreeJS, so thank you for bearing with me!

EDIT #2: Okay so I have made more progress and have the ground tiles laying how I need them to be! Now I have noticed, it appears that half of my tiles are being placed flipped on the X and it causes half of the cylinder to not line up properly.

My updated placement code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.cylinder.geometry.faces.length; i+=2){
      var ground = new Ground("ground", this.preload);
      var afn = this.averageFaceNormals(i);
      ground.model.scene.up = afn.clone().normalize();
      ground.model.scene.lookAt(afn);
      ground.model.scene.rotateX(Math.PI/2);
      ground.model.scene.position.copy(this.calculateFacePositions(i));
      this.cylinder.add(ground.model.scene);
    }
```

This is what it looks like at the halfway mark of my cylinder on both sides:

[image]